# avoid @import being included twice - rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, rails-engines, less-rails

i have a rails engine which is being consumed by an application. The engine and the application both are dependent on a mixin file so both of them does

@import 'mixins'

But on css compression these mixins will be included twice.

Is there anyway to avoid this duplication.

Comment: If you are using Less v.15 and above `import`'s default behavior is that file is imported only once and subsequent import statements for that file will be ignored. http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-once

Comment: Thanks for the link. I played around a bit and saw it was ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple `@import`'s of the same Less file is no longer a problem.  As of Less v1.5, the default behavior of `@import` is to only import that file once.  So you will not get duplicate styles in your compiled stylesheet.

For more info see the Less docs: [Import once](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-once)